# Weird things found in Alocasia plant soil

Tags: houseplants, indoors, soil, roots

Today I wanted to change the soil in my *Alocasia* plant, but I found these things in the soil, around the roots. They weren't attachments, they where just laying in the soil. I bought in in an IKEA store.
Does any of you know what this is?

[image]

Comment: They look a bit like lily bulbs - I'd pot them up separately and see if anything grows in spring...They don't look like offset corms from Alocasia, which was my first thought.

Comment: Are they soft and somewhat squishy or are they hard?  Can you wash them off and post picture of them washed on a neutral background?

Answer (score 1):

*Alocasias* have bulbs and can be grown from bulbs, [How to grow an Alocasia from a bulb](https://www.olleriksson.com/blog/how-to-grow-an-alocasia-from-a-bulb). So what you have found in the pot are unsprouted *Alocasia* bulbs.

These plants often could go dormant, loosing all of their leaves and becoming a stump just to regrow from the bulb next spring.

Here is an *Alocasia* bulb from the article above.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That was my thought too when I saw them. these little 'bulbules'? come from around the flower normally, and don't resemble offsets from the roots of the plant. However I am not familiar with Alocasia so don't know whether it produces them.